# Python: Deleting Key in Nested Dictionary Gives Error

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing a class project on making a text based game. It's going well except for when I try to delete the item from the room after the player picks it up. In this case I am trying to delete a key from a nested dictionary. I've tried different ways including a boolean approach but I don't have much practice with booleans and interacting with them in a dictionary.
Here is the code to search a room in the game that I am stuck on:

```
        if 'item' in current_room:
            print('Found the {}, shiny. I will put it in my inventory I guess.'.format(current_room['item']))
            player_inventory.append(current_room['item'])
            print("{}'s inventory :".format(player_name), player_inventory)
            rooms[current_room['item']]
            continue
        else:
            print('There is nothing of interest here, maybe I should search another room.')
            continue
```

This is part of the dictionary:

```
        'name': 'Kitchen',
        'north': 'Main Hall',
        'south': 'Food Storage',
        'item': 'Chef Gem'
```

And here is the error code:

```
  File "C:\Users\jjpun\PycharmProjects\TextGame\main.py", line 122, in <module>
    del rooms[current_room['search']]
KeyError: 'Chef Gem'
```

Comment: The problem is that 'Chef Gem' is not a key, 'Chef Gem' is the value of key 'item'

Comment: Instead of appending `current_room["item"]` do `player_inventory.append(current_room.pop("item"))`. This will simultaneously remove the item from the current room and put it in your player's inventory.

Comment: @ddejohn Thank you for your help and helping me further my understanding! I did some googling on dictionaries but couldn't figure this out. I also didn't know it was possible to pop an item while adding it to the inventory in one line. I appreciate you two <3